# PHP Adding an element to the beginning of an array without changing other array numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays

Since version PHP > 5.4 , the '+' is no longer can be use to combine 2 numeric key array. any alternative to combine 2 numeric key array without change the key? for example

```
myarray1 =  [0 => '-'];
myarray2 = [8 => 'CUACA BURUK' ,
            3 => 'JALAN SESAK' ,
            2 => 'KEMALANGAN' ,
            7 => 'KENDERAAN ROSAK' ,
            6 => 'KURSUS/BENGKEL/SEMINAR' ,
            9 => 'LAIN-LAIN' ,
            4 => 'LAWATAN TAPAK/KERJA LUAR' ,
            5 => 'MESYUARAT',
            ];
```

I want to create a combo box, the second array is an array that I get from my database and want to and additional blank option to user. I want retain the key and the element when merge the 2 array. If I using the array_merge, it will change the key.

Comment: somewhat confuse however: `$myarray2[0]='-';` seems to be all you need

Comment: What about [`array_unshift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)?

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want to add one element to the array, I suggest populating an array from the database, then using an element assignment to create the **-** element, like so:

```
$options = [ /* Values from database */ ];
$options[0] = '-';
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why think that. `$myarray1 + $myarray2` is and always has been a union in PHP. That behavior has never changed. A union and `array_merge` do two very different things, however. `$myarray1 + $myarray2` will add elements to `$myarray1` from `$myarra2` who's keys do not already exist in `$myarray1`. `array_merge($myarray1, $myarray2)` will merge all elements together **if the keys are numeric** and overwrite string keys.

So in your example above...

```
<?php
$myarray1 = [0 => '-'];
$myarray2 = [
             8 => 'CUACA BURUK',
             3 => 'JALAN SESAK',
             2 => 'KEMALANGAN',
             7 => 'KENDERAAN ROSAK',
             6 => 'KURSUS/BENGKEL/SEMINAR',
             9 => 'LAIN-LAIN',
             4 => 'LAWATAN TAPAK/KERJA LUAR',
             5 => 'MESYUARAT'
            ];

$newArray = $myarray1 + $myarray2;

var_dump($newArray);
```

You get...

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "-"
  [8]=>
  string(11) "CUACA BURUK"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "JALAN SESAK"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "KEMALANGAN"
  [7]=>
  string(15) "KENDERAAN ROSAK"
  [6]=>
  string(22) "KURSUS/BENGKEL/SEMINAR"
  [9]=>
  string(9) "LAIN-LAIN"
  [4]=>
  string(24) "LAWATAN TAPAK/KERJA LUAR"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "MESYUARAT"
}
```

In everything from [PHP 4.3.0 to PHP 7.0.0](https://3v4l.org/DfVbn) (tested with 3v4l.org).